# cannot start greenplum - gpstart failed

Tags: java, postgresql, greenplum

I was trying to update to the latest java on my greenplum machine and changed the path variable to the latest java folder.

Since then I have not been able to start the greenplumdb. Whenever i run the gpstart command ..  i get the following error

> **`gpstart failed. (Reason ='[Errno -2] name or service not known') exiting...`**

if i start with trace on i.e. `gpstart -v` ..i get the following output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib/python/gppylib/mainUtils.py", line 280, in simple_main_locked
    exitCode = commandObject.run()
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db/./bin/gpstart", line 152, in run
    success=self._start(segmentsToStart, invalidSegments, inactiveSegments)
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db/./bin/gpstart", line 431, in _start
    segmentStartResult = segmentStartOp.startSegments(self.gparray, segmentsToStart, startMode, self.era)
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib/python/gppylib/operations/startSegments.py", line 107, in startSegments
    failedPings=self.hostcache.ping_hosts(self.__workerPool)
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib/python/gppylib/gphostcache.py", line 260, in ping_hosts
    p = unix.Ping('ping', key)
  File "/usr/local/greenplum-db/lib/python/gppylib/commands/unix.py", line 338, in __init__
    addrinfo = socket.getaddrinfo(hostToPing, None)
gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
20150302:19:32:30:004960 gpstart:NHD7:h-user-[DEBUG]:-WorkerPool haltWork()
20150302:19:32:30:004960 gpstart:NHD7:h-user-[DEBUG]:-[worker0] haltWork
20150302:19:32:30:004960 gpstart:NHD7:h-user-[DEBUG]:-[worker1] haltWork
20150302:19:32:30:004960 gpstart:NHD7:h-user-[DEBUG]:-[worker2] haltWork
20150302:19:32:30:004960 gpstart:NHD7:h-user-[DEBUG]:-[worker3] haltWork
20150302:19:32:30:004960 gpstart:NHD7:h-user-[DEBUG]:-[worker4] haltWork
```

I am not sure what's going on and did not find anything online. Even the log files don't have a lot of useful information

Here are some of the lines from the log file

```
2015-03-02 16:23:44.484715 PST,"h-user","template1",p2864,th600786688,"127.0.0.1","37265",2015-03-02 16:23:44 PST,669508,,cmd1,seg-1,,,x669508,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: BEGIN",,,,,,"BEGIN",0,,"postgres.c",1535,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.484931 PST,"h-user","template1",p2864,th600786688,"127.0.0.1","37265",2015-03-02 16:23:44 PST,669508,,cmd2,seg-1,,,x669508,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: SET CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES='ERROR'",,,,,,"SET CLIENT_MIN_MESSAGES='ERROR'",0,,"postgres.c",1535,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.485085 PST,"h-user","template1",p2864,th600786688,"127.0.0.1","37265",2015-03-02 16:23:44 PST,669508,,cmd3,seg-1,,,x669508,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: COMMIT",,,,,,"COMMIT",0,,"postgres.c",1535,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.485255 PST,"h-user","template1",p2864,th600786688,"127.0.0.1","37265",2015-03-02 16:23:44 PST,669509,,cmd4,seg-1,,,x669509,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: BEGIN",,,,,,"BEGIN",0,,"postgres.c",1535,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.485434 PST,"h-user","template1",p2864,th600786688,"127.0.0.1","37265",2015-03-02 16:23:44 PST,669509,,cmd5,seg-1,,,x669509,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: SELECT procpid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE procpid != pg_backend_pid()",,,,,,"SELECT procpid FROM pg_stat_activity WHERE procpid != pg_backend_pid()",0,,"postgres.c",1535,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.487916 PST,"h-user","template1",p2864,th600786688,"127.0.0.1","37265",2015-03-02 16:23:44 PST,669509,,cmd7,seg-1,,,x669509,sx1,"LOG","00000","statement: SELECT typname, typlen FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23",,,,,,"SELECT typname, typlen FROM pg_type WHERE oid=23",0,,"postgres.c",1535,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.503684 PST,,,p2837,th600786688,,,,0,,,seg-1,,,,,"LOG","00000","received fast shutdown request",,,,,,,0,,"postmaster.c",4164,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.504823 PST,,,p2842,th600786688,,,,0,,,seg-1,,,,,"LOG","00000","shutting down",,,,,,,0,,"xlog.c",8265,
2015-03-02 16:23:44.511021 PST,,,p2842,th600786688,,,,0,,,seg-1,,,,,"LOG","00000","database system is shut down",,,,,,,0,,"xlog.c",8287,
```

any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i fixed the issue by adding a mapping to the /etc/hosts file..i have no idea what broke it in the first place but it is working for now

Reference :- https://support.pivotal.io/hc/communities/public/questions/203012917-cannot-start-greenplum-gpstart-failed

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not with Greenplum, the command failing is `socket.getaddrinfo(hostToPing, None)`. Most likely you have selinux runnign on the machines, disable it

Comment: i fixed the issue by adding a mapping in the /etc/hosts file